# ORA-03113 Error while opening the database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to restore a database. The job was hung do to some issue, so I have restarted the Oracle service (Windows). I'm now getting an error while connecting to DB:

```
ORA-03113 end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID :9716
Session ID: 237 serial number :5
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ORA-03113` is a generic error. Please read this excellent post [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/m_ora_03113_end_of_file_on_communications_channel.htm) for some information as to the root cause analysis of this error.

As a workaround for your case, assuming you can afford to reset the logs, you can probably do an incomplete database recovery and then open the database with `RESETLOGS` option:

```
SQL> STARTUP MOUNT;

SQL> ALTER DATABASE RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL CANCEL;

SQL> ALTER DATABASE RECOVER CANCEL;

SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS;
```

Comment: On the third line, I got this error: `ORA-01112: media recovery not started`

Comment: @JLewkovich During the process, do you see the below errors:

`ORA-01547: warning: RECOVER succeeded but OPEN RESETLOGS would get error below
ORA-01194: file XXX needs more recovery to be consistent`

If yes, then it means you need to apply archived logs. and if that's the case, probably your issue is not exactly same as what OP has been faced with.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
SQL> STARTUP MOUNT;

SQL> ALTER DATABASE RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL CANCEL;

SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS;
```

Answer (score 0):

it helped to me.

```
SQL> STARTUP MOUNT;
SQL> ALTER DATABASE RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL CANCEL;
SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS;
```